# Trouble with using OAuth LinkedIN for Android SDK

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to run an OAuth in my android app to get user data from LinkedIn and as i just started on the project i have run into a major bug/issue. After requesting the token from the following code, the token doesn't get received and the app continues to open in the on-phone browser used for the authentication. 
Any help would be appreciated as I am really new to android development.

```
    package com.tushar.linkedinauth;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInAccessToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "MyConsumerKey";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "MyConsumerSecret";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 new AutheticateLinkedIn().execute();
            }
        });
        Log.d("Token", " Starting Task");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if(liToken!=null)
        {
        Log.d("Token", "New Intent Recieved");
        String verifier = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);    
        Log.d("Token", "Posting update");
        client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");
        Log.d("Token", "Update Posted");
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.onNewIntent(intent);
//      
//    }


    public class AutheticateLinkedIn extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean>
    {



        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Token", " Requested");
            liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;  
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            Log.d("Token", " Recieved");
//          mDialog.cancel();

    }
}
}
```